# Vector.add Vector.get and that with methods and arrays

Tags: java, arrays, list, vector, methods

Ok guys, I am doing the same thing since 2pm. I am looking for the fault. I need your help, i made up an similar question but i need to ask again.
Please help me....

```
  import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

public class TippSpeicher {
    Tipp t = new Tipp();
    Lottospiel spiel = new Lottospiel();
    int[] feld;
    List<int[]> tipspeicher = new Vector<int[]>(Arrays.asList(feld));


public void tippsabspeichern(){
    feld=spiel.getTipp(); //geTipp is a method returning an array.
    tipspeicher.add(0, feld);
    feld = tipspeicher.get(0);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(feld)); // here i can see the array
                                   from getTipp; so far everything is fine.
}
public int[] tippAbrufen(){ // in this method i want to create the
                            possibility to gain acces to the Vector for other classes.
    int [] fld = tipspeicher.get(0);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fld));
    return fld;
    // doesnt help if i take the array feld that i created before bytheway.
}
}

// Completly knew class here:
     public void auswertung(){  
        TippSpeicher ts = new TippSpeicher();
        Ziehungsspeicher zs= new Ziehungsspeicher();
        int[] tippfeld=ts.tippAbrufen();
         int[] ziehungsfeld=zs.ziehungAbrufen();
    .... this method goes on but there can't be the fault.
```

So I hope you get what i wanted to reach... but somehow it doesnt work.

I generate an array. Want to safe it. And want to get it back out of the vector.(!yes it needs to be an vector).

MY result what it get is null; so there need to be a fault in the saving method... at least thats what i think.

Comment: You'll probably get more more help if you format your code more carefully and refrain from the totally unprofessional language.

Comment: Why exactly do you need the vector? Tippspeicher seems to hold only one item ever. So just use feld and be happy! And you don't save a tipp before getting it. So it will still be null.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell from the scacre code sample, but if tipspeicher contains null entries, then the reason is likely that Lottospiel.getTipp() returns null instead of an array. You should check the implementation of Lottospiel.

To debug this, try to add an IF statement before every place you insert into the vector, i.e.

```
if(feld == null) throw new RuntimeException("feld was null");
```

or even better, step through the code in a debugger.